# The proper way of using "yield" in this example

Tags: python, yield

I'm trying to demonstrate how `yield` in Python is used. I want to demonstrate that through an example.

The example will ask the user to enter `yes` or `no`, and increase the counter `n` by 1 every time `yes` is entered.

The part I want to show how `yield` works is when the user calls the function again, and getting an updated value of the number of times. For instance, if return was used, and the user runs the script again, it will start from scratch and the number of times would be `1`. Rather, I want the user to get 1,2,3,...etc, that is the number of times yes was entered.

The issue here is how to use `yield` to demonstrate such example. In the code I wrote below, I always get a `generator object` returned rather than the value of `n`. How can I get the integer value `n` returned instead?

```
def yes_times(answer):
    n = 0
    if answer == 'yes':
        n = n + 1
        yield n


answer = raw_input('"yes" or "no": ')
times = yes_times(answer)
print 'You answered yes ' + str(times) + ' times'
```

Thanks.

Comment: That's not at all how (or when) to use generator functions. You're only taking input once!

Comment: generators are used mainly when you want to operate on large data sets because they are evaluated lazily and save memory not on single input @jonrsharpe stated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, you can try:

```
def yes_times(answer = None):
    count = 0
    while True:
        if answer=="yes":
            count += 1
            answer = yield count
        else:
            answer = yield count


gen = yes_times()
gen.next()
while True:
    answer = raw_input('"yes" or "no": ')
    print 'You answered yes ' + str(gen.send(answer)) + ' times'
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to demonstrate how `yield` in Python is used.
>
> ... example problem ...
>
> The issue here is how to use `yield` to demonstrate such example.

You're doing this backwards.

Don't demonstrate how `yield` is used by picking some arbitrary example, which is unrelated to generator behaviour, and try implementing it using `yield`.

Instead, choose something that `yield` is good at, and implement that - ideally with a comparable non-`yield` implementation so you can show the benefits.

---

Simple example: toy implementation of `range`

```
def naive_range(begin, end):
    i = begin
    result = []
    while i < end:
        result.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    return result

def generate_range(begin, end):
    i = begin
    while i < end:
        yield i
        i = i + 1
```

Now, can you name the drawbacks of the naive implementation? When will it be significantly worse than the generator, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to use the generator as if it were a function.  I strongly recommend that you go through a tutorial on line until you grasp the difference -- after all, that's how I quit making exactly this mistake.  :-)

Your statement

```
times = yes_times(answer)
```

instantiates the generator, which is what you get when you print.  Instead, you need to either use the **next** function ...

```
times = next(yes_times(answer))
```

... or properly employ a generator that does what you need.  The general use of a generator is to recognize it as a *stream* of data, something like

```
for times in yes_times(answer):
```

However, this requires that you update your generator to get the input itself.

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: It is really still not clear, especially how to do that with the for-statement you mentioned. Thanks

Comment: A generator produces a stream of results.  The typical use consumes that stream, one result at a time.  The **for** statement iterates through the sequence of results.  @Useless did this very well in another answer here.